# Calculating weighted average when some values are negative

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate the weighted average of stock prices but the problem is that some values are negative (where some but not all stocks were sold) and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Here is how I manged to do it with only positive values and it works fine:

[image: Only positives]

But if I try with some negative values added in I get an error:
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `sumproduct()` to calculate the weighted sum, and divide that by the total quantity, like this:

```
=sumproduct( 
  filter(H$2:H, G$2:G = J2), 
  filter(I$2:I, G$2:G = J2) 
) / sum(filter(H$2:H, G$2:G = J2))
```